# Spark Job Hold a While in "Sending RPC" Log

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hdp

I have a Spark Job,
When Running Job on a YARN Cluster (HDP 3.1), After A long Time (about 1hour) i get this Message on Trace Log and Job Nothing to Do, After That Job Create Executers and Running Successfully.
How can I Fix This Waiting Time? Is That a Bug or Misconfiguration on My Cluster?

this is message i get :

> TRACE TransportClient: Sending RPC to datanode01.local/192.168.x.x/192.168.66.43:45564
> TRACE TransportClient: Sending request 5477612075831031235 to datanode01.local/192.168.x.x:45564 took 1 ms
> TRACE MessageDecoder: Received message RpcResponse: RpcResponse{requestId=5477612075831031235, body=NettyManagedBuffer{buf=PooledUnsafeDirec
> tByteBuf(ridx: 21, widx: 102, cap: 128)}}

I Test It Several Time,
And I Found If I Run Job Once a Day, A Day After That Job Run Successful Without Waiting and Day After That Waiting a Lot.
This Happened Every Day.